# Computing $v.∇α$

Tags: vector-analysis

Consider a vector field $v$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$ which satisfies $∇\cdot v=0$, **and** $∇×v=αv$ for some $α:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$. My aim is to compute $v\cdot ∇α$.

I let v(x,y,z) = (U,V,W)
Using this, I computed $∇\cdot v$, and found that $\frac {\partial U}{\partial x} + \frac {\partial V}{\partial y} + \frac {\partial W}{\partial z} = 0$

Then I computed $∇×v$, and found that $(\frac {\partial W}{\partial y}- \frac {\partial V}{\partial z}, \frac {\partial U}{\partial z}- \frac {\partial W}{\partial x}, \frac {\partial V}{\partial x}- \frac {\partial U}{\partial y}) = αv$, and hence came up with the following three equations:

$\frac {\partial W}{\partial y}- \frac {\partial V}{\partial z} = αU$

$\frac {\partial U}{\partial z}- \frac {\partial W}{\partial x} = αV$

$\frac {\partial V}{\partial x}- \frac {\partial U}{\partial y} = αW$

From this I can maybe deduce that:

$$\frac {\frac {\partial W}{\partial y}- \frac {\partial V}{\partial z}}{U} 
 = \frac{\frac {\partial U}{\partial z}- \frac {\partial W}{\partial x}}{V} = \frac{\frac {\partial V}{\partial x}- \frac {\partial U}{\partial y}}{W} = α $$

though I'm unsure of the validity of the above statement.

I'm unsure of what to do after this point and if what anything I have shown will help me to compute $v\cdot ∇α$. I am aware that I should be getting an answer of $0$.

Any assistance would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$\nabla \cdot \nabla \times v = 0; \tag 1$

the divergence of a curl is *always* $0$; thus the given

$\nabla \times v = \alpha v \tag 2$

yields

$\nabla \cdot (\alpha v) = 0; \tag 3$

also, by hypothesis

$\nabla \cdot v = 0; \tag 4$

now we have the identity (see [this wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities))

$\nabla \cdot (\alpha v) = \nabla \alpha \cdot v + \alpha \nabla \cdot v; \tag 5$

(3), (4)  and (5) together yield

$v \cdot \nabla \alpha = 0. \tag 6$

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that

$$
\nabla \cdot (\nabla \times {\bf v}) = 0
$$

so that

$$
0 = \nabla \cdot (\nabla \times {\bf v}) = \nabla\cdot(\alpha {\bf v}) = \alpha (\nabla\cdot {\bf v}) + (\nabla a)\cdot {\bf v} = (\nabla a)\cdot {\bf v}
$$